# SSIS 2005 changing connection server for "Execute SQL Task" has no effect --

Tags: visual-studio-2005, ssis

I created SSIS packages a while ago, today I need to re-point them to a different SQL server. I have a bunch of "Execute SQL Task" tasks, which need their Connection property changed to a different server.

I created a new connection manager, double-clicked on each of the sql tasks, changed their Connection property to the new one, ran. It failed, the error was that it could not find the old connection. I restarted the project, none of the SQL Server tasks seem to pick up the new Connection Manager. I opened up the .dtsx files, tried to find the old server name somewhere and manually change it, but I could not find the old server.

What do I have to change to get rid of the old SQL Server and make it connect to the new, correct data source.

I work in VS2005, on Windows 2008 x64 machine (I don't know if it matters or not).

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this occur before when Package Configurations are enabled.  Make sure that this is not the case, recompile, and try again.

Comment: Not really a good solution for those that use external package configurations. I have seen this problem before while using Package Configurations, and if you modify the configuration (connection string) for the failing DB connection this should solve the issue. For example, the Connection String for Access DB's tend to default out to a bloated string. I find removing the properties to make the connection string lightweight should solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

all you had to do is change the connection string in the old  connection manager

make a new one if you deleted the old one and in all the tasks select the new one, even if you create a new one with the same name as the old one it won't work because somewhere internal a guid is used

Comment: Good note on the guid, I did not think about that. As for the rest -- I made sure in all my tasks the new connection is selected, but it still does not want to work.

Comment: Still did not work. I reverted to the original version of the package in TFS, so started from the beginning. Changed the connection string, left everything else alone. Now I get the error: [Execute SQL Task] Error: Failed to acquire connection "MYNAME". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if package configuration is enabled. The package may still be getting the configuration of the old server from the package configuration.

Comment: That was it. I did not chose your answer as the accepted answer because the key words were "Package Configuration" and, since I am relatively new to SSIS, they were important for me to know what was going on. So your phrase "configuration is enabled" did not make a lot of sense to me. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

try recompiling after making the changes.

Comment: Recompiling the SSIS package? I didn't know that was possible.